# UIImagePickerController broken on iPad IOS9

Tags: swift, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

This bug occurs when selecting an image (`sourceType = .PhotoLibrary`) within a `UIImagePickerController`. After making edits and selecting the USE button the returned image the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is incorrect. The image only displays the top right hand corner of the selected image from library.

I've tested this on an iPad and simulator using iOS 9 and the bug is consistent (ok on iPhones). All works fine with iOS 8 or lower. If you've got an iPad app that utilizises a UIImagePickerController could you please check if you have the same problem. Anybody got any ideas to work round this problem?